# Tips transfer how to set

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, transfer

Is there any way to send a small amount of eth to another wallet many times in one click? Also known as spam

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you mean, you cant simply multiply a coin because you feel like it. thats not how it works, but if all your trying to do is make something annoying, yeah, that can be done.

```
contract shutUpAndTakeMyMoney1{

constructor{
owner = msg.sender;
uint x = 0;
}



function ShutUpAndTakeMyMoney(){
if x < 100 ;
print("hello World");
x++;
elseif
print("spaming complete")
x-100;
}
}
```

you basically just need to take this logic, instead of printing hello world, you need to replace that with your ethereum transfer logic. decide how much you want to transfer and replace the 100 with how many times you want to spam. and its done. but, and in all honesty. i cant imagine a single use for that code. but i taught myself how to do that in lua code when i was 14. and loops are always fairly easy.

for example we could also do a bool

```
constructor{
owner = msg.sender;
bool x = Eth.Balance > 0;
}


function iNeedMoreHandsToHoldAllThisEth(){
if x = true;
print("Hold This Eth")
elseif x = false;
print("alright, my three arms can carry the rest of this");
else
print("unknown Error");
}
```

in this way you would replace "hold this eth" with your ethereum trading logic, the other areas with print(""); you can put in a message when you run out of eth to send and if you have any errors that your logic cant work around.
either way you do it youll have to form a loop in one of the two ways, either with math or with variables. and in that loop will be your trading logic.
if you do not want to completely run out of eth all you gotta do for the bool method is specify the amount greater than 0 that eth has to be for x to be false. and whatever number that is, is the ammount of eth you will be left with. please keep in mind these are examples only. more research may be neccesary if youre not familiar with eth trading logic.